# How to deploy a Windows 2016 server instance with two network interfaces

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Please help me on below steps to deploy windows 2016 Instance on GCP.

1)Deploy a Windows 2016 server instance with two network interfaces. 
Configure the first network interface with an internal 
only connection to the new VPC subnet, and the second network interface with an internal only connection to the default VPC network.

2)Install a second Windows 2016 server instance with two network interfaces. 
Configure the first network interface to connect to the new VPC subnet with an ephemeral public (external NAT) address, 
and the second network interface with an internal only connection to the default VPC network. This is the jump box or bastion host.

Comment: This question would be better asked on Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks.Now i can able to deploy the instances.